# How to disable Micronaut auto-reload feature?

Tags: micronaut, livereload

My Micronaut app is being auto restarted every time I change any file (`md`, `js`, `html`) outside of `src/` directory.

On app start I see this line in the log:

```
Watching for changes in [myapp, myapp/src/main/java, myapp/src/main/resources]
```

So, server is watching for changes in the project root, which is completely wrong.

I tried to disable every option in [`micronaut.io.watch.*`](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/configurationreference.html), but it has no effect.

How to disable this feature? I neither need or want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of the Micronaut Maven plugin, and it can be disabled by passing the `mn.watch` flag when running, e.g., `./mvnw mn:run -Dmn.watch=false`, or you can edit your pom and add a `<watchForChanges>` element. See the docs at https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-maven-plugin/latest/run-mojo.html